# object 'wcol' not found: h2o.gbm error within mlr package in r

Tags: r, h2o, mlr

I'm running into this error whenever I try to run h2o gbm:

```
Error in h2o::h2o.gbm(y = y, x = x, training_frame = h2of, weights_column = wcol,  : 
  object 'wcol' not found
```

I have tried reinstalling h2o but I have just been running into this error.

```
data(BostonHousing, package = "mlbench")
regr.task = makeRegrTask(id = "bh", data = BostonHousing, target = "medv")

lrn = makeLearner("regr.h2o.gbm")

outer = makeResampleDesc("Holdout")
r = resample(
  learner = lrn,
  task = regr.task,
  resampling = outer,
  show.info = TRUE
)
```

Comment: add `wcol=NULL` before resample and that should solve your error

Comment: where would I add it?

Comment: Add it before this line `r = resample(`

Comment: This is what I get now: predictLearner for regr.h2o.gbm has returned a class character instead of a numeric!

Comment: It looks like a bug. I have created a issue in github for it. https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2630